# How to pass dynamic props with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to pass props using Vue, I thought of JSON with object that includes name and value. I need to pass data to a different component but it changes as in each event the names and values change.
So for example I might have name: 'a' value: 'b', name: 'f' value: 'k' and in anorher event name: 'c' value: 'd' 
my code that works but it work because i return hard coded data

```
data() {
    return {
        params: {
            name:'bill',
            value:'jones'
        },
```

in child

```
@Component({
    props:
    {
        urls: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => { return {name:'', value: ''} }
    },
    }
```

function with object params that i need to get the data from

```
getParams(url) {

            paramsData[key] = value;
            //console.log(key,value);
        }
        return params;
        console.log(params)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use computed property names

```
emitEvent(name, value) {
  let objectToEmit = {
    [name]: value,
  };
  this.$emit("event-name", objectToEmit);
}
```

Now `name` and `value` will be set according to whatever you pass in `emitEvent` function.

You can read more about computed property names on below link 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much pass anything through and you can do it in many ways. Here are 4 examples:

Note: for all options we are assuming you have a parent component that is using the following syntax

```
  <example-component :name="somename" :value="somevalue"></example-component>
```

**Option1:** props as a list of array of strings. The values can be anything in JS i.e. numbers, strings, objects, functions

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p v-text="example"></p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ExampleComponent",
        prop: ['name','value']
    }
</script>
```

**Option 2:** most common approach. Every prop to be a specific type of value. In these cases, you can list props as an object, where the properties’ names and values contain the prop names and types, respectively

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p v-text="example"></p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ExampleComponent",
        props: {
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
                default: 'something'
            },
            value: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

**Option 3:** you can validate or in this case pass in an Object and defaults returned from a factory function so you will always have some value. You can even return validation `validator: function (value) {...}`

```
<template>
    <div>
<!--     some value from EventServiceClass-->
        <p v-text="example.name"></p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import EventServiceClass from "./EventServiceClass";

    export default {
        name: "ExampleComponent",
        props: {
            example: {
                type: Object,
                default: function () {
                    return {name:'a', value: 'b'}
                }
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

**Option 4:** a little more advanced but in this example we are bind get and set to input properties on a form, which we would use to create factory form components

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input
            id="name"
            type="text"
            v-model="name"
            class="form--input light"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ExampleComponent",
        props: {
            name: {
                type: String,
                default: ""
            }
        },
        computed: {
            name: {
                get() {
                    return this.value;
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$emit("input", value);
                }
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment!! i am trying to use approche 3 but with no success. i will edit my question with updated code